# Kiddush in Schul on Yom-Tov

Tags: minhag, yom-tov, kiddush, maariv

In those communities where kiddush is still said before Aleinu on Shabbat (Friday night), is it also said on leyl (the night of) yom-tov?

As this question relates to my effort with the creation of a siddur, I wish to get answers based mainly on Ashkenazi usage, although all answers are of course welcome.

Answer (score 3):

While many shuls don't make Kiddush on Sukkoth, Many others do.  According to the Mishanah Berurah only the 1st 2 nights of Pesach are exempt.  (See ArtScroll Machzor.)
In some places the chazzan or Shamash makes Kiddush in the shul's Sukkah if there is one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, except for the 1st two nights of Pesach when there is an obligation for people to make Seder and drink 4 cups of wine. Kiddush, then, is the 1st cup.

Source: [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Kiddush#Kiddish_in_Shul). There is a debate if, nowadays, we should be saying Kiddush in shul, altogether.

> In the days of the gemara, the Rabbis instituted saying Kiddish in
>   shul for the travelers who would eat and drink in the Shul. Nowadays,
>   when guests don't eat their meals in shul, some say that its proper
>   not to say Kiddush in shul, while others uphold this minhag to say
>   Kiddush in shul on Friday night

I have several shuls in my neighborhood. In one shul, they say it (I can't convince them to get rid of that sweet stuff). Another shul, they never make Kiddush (Personally, I think the reason is more that the shul has a strict "no alcohol (including Kiddush wine) ever, anywhere in the building." They've had problems with young kids, as well as adults getting drunk. They have no fridge to store grape juice long enough without someone else "stealing" it during the week. They rent the facility from others.)

Comment: Note that the first night of Sukkot (and the second and eighth in the Diaspora) can be problematic depending on where and by whom Kiddush is being said.